# OR condition in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to check whether a number is divisible by one of 3, 5, or 7.

How could I write a rule something like -

```
isDivide(N) :- N mod 3 =:= 0 OR  N mod 5 =:= 0 OR N mod 7 =:= 0.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
isDivide(N) :- N mod 3 =:= 0. 
isDivide(N) :- N mod 5 =:= 0. 
isDivide(N) :- N mod 7 =:= 0.
```

alternatively:

```
isDivide(N) :- 
    N mod 3 =:= 0 
    ;  N mod 5 =:= 0 
    ; N mod 7 =:= 0.
```

Note that `;` is not at the end of the line but at the beginning of the next line.
This is purely a matter of style but it's strongly recommended to follow it.